# Dipole of a Particle in Quantum Harmonic Potential Subject to Electric field

Tags: quantum-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, dipole-moment

Consider a quantum particle in harmonic potential subject to electric field in the positive $x$ direction. The Hamiltonian of this system has the form

$$\hat{H}=\frac{1}{2}m\omega^{2}\hat{x}^{2}-qE\hat{x}$$

which we can factor out achieving

$$\hat{H}=\frac{1}{2}m\omega^{2}\left(\hat{x}-\frac{qE}{m\omega^{2}}\right)^{2}-\frac{q^{2}E^{2}}{2m\omega^{2}}$$

From this we can clearly get the shift of the energy levels and the average position

$$\left<\hat{x}\right>=\frac{qE}{m\omega^{2}}$$
$$\Delta E_{n}=-\frac{q^{2}E^{2}}{2m\omega^{2}}$$

Now, we now that the dipole moment $p$ satisfies

$$p=q\left<\hat{x}\right>$$
$$\Delta E_{n}=-pE$$

Those expressions give answers differ by a factor of $2$. I guess there is something missing with my definition of the dipole moment. Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: First guess is that this is the adiabatic charge build up "1/2". Energy is not the same as the potential. One needs to consider how to build up the 'electrostatic' situation from 0 field as an energy reference, and the 1/2 comes from integration from zero field to E.